# What is the payload to be sent for “ViewFields” parameter as part of consuming the SPO REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spview

I am trying to create a SharePoint list view through the SharePoint REST API, with a defined set of columns to be part of the view. The endpoint i am using is below:

POSTMAN API Request:

HTTP METHOD: POST

URL: [https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/SPSite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/views](https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/SPSite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(%27ListName%27)/views) Headers:

'Accept' - 'application/json;odata=verbose'
'Content-Type' - 'application/json;odata=verbose'
Body (JSON):

```
{
"__metadata":{
    "type":"SP.View"
},
"Title":"TestViewTHI",
"ViewQuery":["Name","Title"]
```

}

I get a JSON error, since this payload does not seem to be right. Need help in understanding how to create a view with specific fields through the SharePoint REST API.

Thanks, Yesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the body you should pass CAML Query for attribute `"ViewQuery"`. Reference:https://www.codesharepoint.com/rest-api/create-view-in-sharepoint-using-rest-api

If you don't want to add filter/order in the view. You could just ignore it. For example:

```
{
"__metadata":{
    "type":"SP.View"
},
"Title":"TestView",
"PersonalView": false,
"ViewType": "HTML"
}
```

After you create the view, you could add/remove fields with the endpoint:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/michael/_api/Web/Lists/getbytitle('TestList')/Views/getbytitle('TestView')/ViewFields/addviewfield('FieldName')

https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/michael/_api/Web/Lists/getbytitle('TestList')/Views/getbytitle('TestView')/ViewFields/RemoveViewField('FieldName')
```

Read here for more: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn531433(v=office.15)#viewfieldcollection-resource

Comment: - Thank you for the response. So, if i have a collection of 5 fields to be added to the view, does that mean i have to iterate through the collection and add one field at a time to the view?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for clarifying this. This helps.